# Firebase orderByChild Ignored

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I sort the following structure in Firebase by sortOrder?

```
categories {
    {
        "b": {
            "name": "Banana",
            "sortOrder": 2
        },
        "a": {
            "name": "Apple",
            "sortOrder": 1
        }
    }
}
```

From the documentation it looks as simple as:

```
ref('categories').orderByChild('sortOrder').once('value') ...
```

However, the first node returned is banana. It doesn't matter what string value I use. For example, the following returns the same results:

```
ref('categories').orderByChild('xxx').once('value') ...
```

Full function:

```
public list(): Observable<Category[]> {

    let ref = firebase.database().ref('categories').orderByChild('sortOrder');

    return Observable.fromPromise(<Promise<any>>ref.once('value'))
        .flatMap(snapshot => {
            let objects = snapshot.val();
            let categories: Array<Category> = new Array();

            for (let key in objects) {
                let category: Category = objects[key];
                category.code = key;
                categories.push(category);
            }

            return Observable.of(categories);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: How are you accessing the children in the callback?

Comment: Added all function code to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you access the children via the snapshot's value's keys, the order is indeterminate.

You need to use the snapshot's `forEach` method:

```ts
return Observable.fromPromise(<Promise<any>>ref.once('value'))
    .flatMap(snapshot => {
        let categories: Array<Category> = new Array();
        snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
            let category: Category = childSnapshot.val();
            category.code = childSnapshot.key;
            categories.push(category);
        });
        return Observable.of(categories);
    }
);
```

Also, you could just use `map` and return `categories`.